# Web Service using HTTP Protocol in Android

Tags: android

can anyone give me an idea of using web service using HTTP protocol.

Comment: there are many way to use web service.. for exmaple follow this [link.](http://blog.dahanne.net/2009/08/16/how-to-access-http-resources-from-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for "Executing a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient":

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "123"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "Paresh"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use web services in our application to send and receive data from a remote server. Consider the case of an login section from a application where you need to pass username and password to the server for checking the whether the user is a valid user or not. In this case the username and password are attached with a url and send it to the remote server for validation and in response you get a value stating whether the user is a valid user or not. Usually the response will be either in XML format or JSON format from there we need to parse that response to get the necessary values. Check out the following example code in this I have created a class named "parsing" and it using the http protocol to receive a data.

```
public class parsing extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                String postURL = "http://services.digg.com/topics?appkey=http://example.com&type=json";
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                String response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                response=response.trim();
                Log.i("RESPONSE=",response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

See the response on the Logcat and do not for get to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
because we are fetching the data from the remote server which needs internet permission.